# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id"

Tags: django, postgresql

I was trying to change default primary key(automatic id index) to Facebook id, which now returns error I can't understand or avoid even by making  everything as it was previously. So basically I'v just added this line to `userporfile` modal

```
   fb_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

which resulted in following

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "blog_userprofile"
```

How can I fix it? I am using Django 1.8 + PostgreSQL

EDIT: I mean if I delete this line with fb_id the error remains

Comment: I suppose there is already default field **id** for your model, so you can't just keep 2 primary keys for one model. If you need fb_id to be unique, just add "unique=true" instead of "primary_key=True"

Comment: @Fian still how can I fix? Error appears in all cases

Comment: If error persists, it could be a problem with db. Can you test your project with "fb_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)", but on a clean db?

Comment: @Fian I have already created new clear db and tested. The same error persists